# Agreement Update issue

Tags: ios, upload, app-store, ipa

I am trying to upload a new version of an app on my client's itunesconnect. But whenever I am clicking on the + button and then iOS, it is showing me a popup(attached image) with a continue button. Clicking on continue is simply closing the popup and nothing is happening.
I am not sure what is happening. Should I reach out to Apple? or is there anything that I can do to create new version and upload the new build?
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Someone in your team with the legal role (or you if you are a personal membership) needs to go into the tax and banking module to accept the new agreement.

Comment: Yes, I've accepted the new agreement at developer website and the refreshed the itunesconnect. Logged out and then logged in once again. But its same.

Comment: Have you done it in iTunesConnect as well?  There are two agreements as per the dialog.

Comment: Okay, got it. Another agreement is "Agreements, Tax, and Banking".